# Regarding the ellipsoid computed by using the “lifting step”

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, ellipsoids

I have asked a question at mathstackexchange but i have not got an answer yet so i am referencing the question here so that maybe one of you can help in understanding the problem: [Regarding the ellipsoid computed by using the “lifting step”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944651/regarding-the-ellipsoid-computed-by-using-the-lifting-step)

Please do help and thanks in advance. (and sorry for the inconvience)

Comment: Please, wait a few days before asking your question also here.

Comment: Also, if you don't get an answer in a few days and you do cross-post, please add a link to here from the other post stating you have done so, so people's effort is not duplicated on both sites.

Comment: I thank you for you instruction, and i will keep them in mind.