# Relation between determinant and norm of matix vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, normed-spaces

I need your expertise in solving the following problem:

Let $D,V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a diagonal matrix and an orthogonal matrix respectively and let $D^\prime,V^\prime \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1) \times (n+1)}$ be a diagonal matrix and an orthogonal matrix respectively.

Lets denote $G = DV^T$ and $G^\prime = D^\prime {V^\prime}^T$.

It is known that:

- There exists $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $$ \left| \left| G(x - v) \right| \right|_2 \geq \frac{\left| \left| G^\prime \begin{bmatrix}x \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right| \right|_2 }{2}$$
- $\left| {G^\prime}^{-1} \right| = const(d^2) \cdot \left| G \right|$

Is it possible to prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ where $x \neq v$,
$$ \left| \left| G(x - v) \right| \right|_2 \leq const(d^2) \cdot \left| \left| G^\prime \begin{bmatrix}x \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right| \right|_2 ?$$

Please advice and thanks in advance.

Comment: am curious, how are "known things" in your problem proved? Maybe that can open up the problem for others.

Comment: see this question which i have asked earlier (about 1-2 months ago):
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944651/regarding-the-ellipsoid-computed-by-using-the-lifting-step

Comment: Something seems off. If you take $x=v$, then your first inequality forces $G'\begin{bmatrix}v\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=0$, but you are saying that $G'$ is invertible.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, i will edit the question!

Comment: have anyone have a "lead" on the subject? pls help